# How to switch betwen sheets in excel on - Lenovo Mix

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn is not working in Lenovo mix. Can anyone help on the shortcut for moving betwen sheets in excel for Lenovo Mix please.

Answer (score 1):

The Lenovo Mix requires you to press the **Fn** (function) key to activate Page Up and Page Down keys as these are combined with the Up and Down arrow keys on the compact keyboard.

So, you'd have to press **CTRL-FN-UP** and **CTRL-FN-DOWN** for these commands, respectively.